# STS Eclipse version?

Tags: eclipse, spring

Which version of eclipse is STS (SpringToolsSuite) based on?

I am looking to apply a few plugins on STS that target a given Eclipse version.

Comment: STS downloads and versions are listed under this url:
http://spring.io/tools/sts/legacy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current Version I use of STS (2.7.1.RELEASE) is based on Eclipse 3.6.2 (Helios).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a place where these version mappings are enlisted?

Comment: If you've downloaded STS you can look at Menu->Help->About SpringSource Tool Suite->Click on Eclipse.org --> There is the eclipse version listed.

Answer (score 1):

STS 2.7.2, the latest version as of now, is based on Eclipse Helios (3.7.0)

Answer (score 1):

STS 3.4.RELEASE is based on Eclipse 4.3.1 (Kepler)
STS 3.3.0.RELEASE is based on Eclipse 4.2 (Juno)

See http://spring.io/tools/sts/all (as of February 2014) to see the version mapping
for recent releases (but it does not list STS 2.x releases)

If you have STS installed, use Help -> About Spring Tool Suite
then click Installation Details to see the Eclipse.org Eclipse Platform version
(i.e. STS 3.3.0.RELEASE uses Version: 3.8.1.v20130118-180812-9jF7oIBFG8eU2pim-VbIlTuQjY0RWWK3x-bv4I

Answer (score 0):

SpringSource released a new version of STS, 2.8 which is now based on Eclipse Indigo, 3.7.1.  You can find more info on the STS site (http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts)

Comment: How to check it for any version?